# WP REST API GET Method Works But Not The POST Method

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I'm just trying to learn how to develop with WordPress Gutenberg. No problem with GET Method however with the post method anything I try results in an errors message No route was found matching the URL and request method. How can I send the data under a POST method?  Going into store is a bit much for something this simple.

edit.js

```
export default function Edit({attributes, setAttributes }) {

const { getCurrentPostId } = wp.data.select("core/editor");

const onPriceChange = (new_price) =>{
setAttributes({price:new_price});

if(document.readyState != 'loading'){
    woobergSendRequest(new_price);
}else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', woobergSendRequest);
}

}

function woobergSendRequest(new_price){

const post_id = getCurrentPostId();
const get_url = 'wooberg/v2/product?_method&product_id='+post_id+'&product_price='+new_price;
console.log(post_id);

const sendData = {product_id:459,product_price:1.00};

apiFetch( {
    path: 'wooberg/v2/product',
    method:'POST',
    data:sendData
} ).then( data => {
    console.log( data );
} );
   }


 return (



<div { ...useBlockProps() }>

    

<NumberControl
        isShiftStepEnabled={ true }
        onChange={ onPriceChange}
        step={0.01}
        shiftStep={ 0.01 }
        value= { attributes.price}
    />

    
</div>
 );

}
```

index.php

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {

    register_rest_route( 'wooberg/v2', '/product', [
        'method'   => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'wooberg_product_price_callback',
        'args' => [
            'product_id' => [
                'required' => false,
                'type' => 'number,'
            ],

            'product_price' => [
                'required' => false,
                'type' => 'number,'
            ],
        ],
        'permission_callback' => function(){
            return current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );
           
       } 
    ]  
);


 });


  function wooberg_product_price_callback($request){



$product_id = $request->get_param('product_id');
$product_price = $request->get_param('product_price');

$product_id = $request['product_id'];
$product_price = $request['product_price'];
if(! empty($product_id)){

    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $curret_price = $product->get_price;
    $product->set_price($product_price);
    $product->set_regular_price($product_price);
    $product->save();


    $response = $product->get_name() .'Has be update from '. $curret_price .' to '.$product->get_price();
     return rest_ensure_response( $response,200 );
}else{
    $response = "No Id found";
    return new WP_REST_Response( [
        'message' => 'Product was not found',
    ], 400 );
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`apiFetch()` usage](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-api-fetch/#usage) is correct, but you're getting the "No route was found" error because of the `'method'   => 'POST'` part which should actually use `methods` and *not* `method`. (Note that an endpoint can allow one or more HTTP method**s**)

So when it's `method`, it's not used and thus the HTTP method defaults to GET only.

And all you need to do is use `'methods'   => 'POST'` (or `'methods'   => 'GET,POST'` if you wanted to allow both GET and POST methods), and the error would be gone.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea about the method and methods differences.

Comment: Sally, is it possible to set method POST for built-in endpoints like `/posts`? If so, then how to?

Comment: @stckvrw I have never done that, but it does seem possible. However, you should post a new question if you still haven't found a solution and are still looking for one. Cheers!

Comment: @SallyCJ My question is posted more than a week, but still without an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74111675

Comment: this saved me days..